# What are the ramifications of recursively chown'ing the directories on an external drive that currently has 501:dialout or root:root permissions?

Tags: permissions, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi that's running a Raspbmc distribution and I've noticed that a lot of the directories are either owned by the user `501` and the group `dialout` or both the user and group `root`. It's frustrating for me to move files from the main filesystem on the SD card to the external drive because I always need root access (and it makes automating tasks a pain too), so I'd really like to be able to `chown` it to the user `pi`. I've read up a little bit on what the `501` user and the `dialout` group are and don't see why I shouldn't do this, but my knowledge of Unix permissions is basic at best so I'd like to know if I've missed any considerations before I go ahead and change the permissions recursively on the entire drive.

So my question would be: Is there any harm in doing a `chown -R pi` on the external drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a common user between the systems where this disk is moving you can then make the ownership on this disk that single user and you'll no longer have to deal with this.

Simply add a user on both systems, and make sure that this user's UID (user ID) and GID (group ID) are the same numbers on both systems. The names are immaterial, it's the numbers that need to be kept in sync, so that the UID/GID is recognized across both systems as a single user/group.

When creating a user these are the parts that drive the recognition by the system which user/group owns files.

#### Example

Say I have this directory, it's user/group is saml & saml.

```
$ ls -ld .
drwx------. 245 saml saml 32768 Oct 26 22:41 .
```

Using the `-n` switch to `ls` you can see what the numbers are for these fields.

```
$ ls -ldn .
drwx------. 245 500 501 32768 Oct 26 22:41 .
```

So we need to make sure that I have the same user/group on both systems (saml/saml) and the UID/GID needs to be 500/501 as well.

If you look in the `/etc/group` file you'll see the group saml + GID.

```
$ grep "^saml" /etc/group
saml:x:501:
```

Looking in `/etc/passwd` file you'll see the user saml + UID.

```
$ grep "^saml" /etc/passwd
saml:x:500:501:Sam M. (local):/home/saml:/bin/bash
```

When running the `useradd` command you can control what UID/GID to use.

```
$ sudo useradd -u 500 -g 501 saml
```

Comment: @ysim - you can also upvote in addition to accepting 8-)